# Why is my volumetric lighting shown in the viewport but not in the render?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, light, lighting, volumetrics

I am working on Blender 2.93.0, using EVEE as a render engine. My friend (and all the tutorials I've seen) did the exact same thing than I did and has no problem seeing the volumetric lights rendered. I've been looking for hours in online tutorials and still have no idea what the source of the problem is.
Also, I have to point out that I am a beginner, I began learning Blender a few weeks ago, so I really don't know much about rendering. Just to try it out, I checked all the boxes concerning lighting in the render settings and it barely changed anything (I then unchecked them of course). Thanks in advance!

[image: viewport 2]

[image: viewport 1]

[image: Rendered image]

[image: lights]
[image: shadows]

[image: Volumetrics]
[image: World]

[image: Render settings]

Comment: This is something I wouldn't mind taking a look at, if there was a file.  Can't say I know off the top of my head, other than that I'm not a believer in putting volumes in the world.  Need to know what version you're using too, there have been some viewport related bug fixes.

Comment: sorry @user:24636 I had to create another account to respond to you. I wanted to send you my packaged file with blend exchange, but for some reason the service isn't working right now. So here's a [wetransfer link](https://we.tl/t-oQtDzNJZda) I'm on version 2.93.0

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with Cube.010, which is hidden in viewports but not in renders.  When you unhide this object (alt h in 3D viewport, object mode) you get a preview that's roughly the same as you render; when you hide this from renders, you get a render that's roughly the same as your viewport with it hidden.

Look on your outliner for anything with an eye icon and a camera icon that disagree....